# Mailchimp Embed CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, mailchimp

I am trying to embed a mailchimp form on my website - just a simple box to enter email, and subscribe button. You can see it at the bottom of this page: http://db1.15a.myftpupload.com/bennetts-tea/

Here is the code for the MC form:

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px 
Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
/* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet 
or in this style block.
   We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the 
HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="https://lovesometea.us13.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?
u=ac5a13ceef4b95430e423c8ea&amp;id=b50d604a2b" method="post" id="mc-
embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" 
class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address </label>
<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" 
id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
    <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none">
</div>
    <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" 
style="display:none"></div>
</div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good 
things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">
<input type="text" name="b_ac5a13ceef4b95430e423c8ea_b50d604a2b" 
tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" 
name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

I am trying to have a transparent background of the signup, and a green box around the input field. This is the CSS I've been trying, works in the Chrome inspector tool but when I apply to website nothing changes. Am I missing something (well obviously I am, hah) ?

```
.div#mc_embed_signup {
background: transparent;
}

.label[for=mce-EMAIL] {
display: none;
}

#mce-EMAIL {
border: 3px solid #4EAAC1;
display: none;
}

#mc-embedded-subscribe-form {
background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CSS you have to be really careful about what takes priority over something else. Specific rules override broad ones, and later rules override earlier ones.

You have 2 issues:

The input border is not green because `#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group input` is taking priority over `#mce-EMAIL`. To fix this you need to make your CSS rule more specific. Change it to `#mc_embed_signup #mce-EMAIL`

The background is not transparent because it is being overridden by the rules at the beginning of your HTML snippet. Remove this line: `#mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px 
Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }` (or remove the `<style>` block completely)